# the magic of assigning URL to a.href

Tags: javascript, html

On Chrome Developer console, I typed the following codes:

```
> a = document.createElement('a');
> a.href = "http://localhost:4200/setting?q=123&b=aa";
```

Then other properties of this element also owned the according value, for example:

```
> a.search
"?q=123&b=aa"
> a.hostname
"localhost"
> a.port
"4200"
```

I was confused with the results. I just assigned `url` to `href` propety.
Why other properties could have their values at the same time?
What's the magic behind the phenomenon?
Could anyone explain this for me?

Comment: @Mohammed That link is completely unrelated to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What's the magic behind the phenomenon?

No “magic”, but simple *specification*.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAnchorElement:

> [HTMLAnchorElement] inherits properties from its parent, HTMLElement, and implements those from [HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils).
>
> The HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils mixin defines utility methods and properties to work with HTMLAnchorElement and HTMLAreaElement. These utilities allow to deal with common features like URLs.